# One or more multiply defined symbols found, error LNK1169 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker, linker-errors

Sorry for the lack of a descriptive title.
I'm getting an error "one or more multiply defined symbols found"; to be more specific, I'm getting 46 of them. One for each function in my header/source files. Using Visual Studios 2013.

Here is the relevant source code:

augments.h

```
#ifndef AUGMENTS_H_
#define AUGMENTS_H_

namespace Augments {
  // only used for pass-ins for constructors
  enum class Weapon_Type {
    sword
  };

  enum class Head_Type {
    head
  };

  enum class Body_Type {
    body
  };

  // the player (Monster) has a head, body and weapon
  // that augments his abilities. This will mostly
  // be the thing that draws to the screen for each
  // augmentation, but more importantly it contains
  // specific statistics about each one.

  // So if there was a body that was able to fly,
  // there would be a bool that denotes this ability.

  class Head : public Actor {
    const Head_Type type;
  public:
    Head(Head_Type);
    void Update(float dt);
  };

  class Body : public Actor {
    const Body_Type type;
  public:
    Body(Body_Type);
    void Update(float dt);
  };

  class Weapon : public Actor {
    const Weapon_Type type;
  public:
    Weapon(Weapon_Type);
    void Update(float dt);
  };
}

using AugHead = Augments::Head;
using AugBody = Augments::Body;
using AugWep  = Augments::Weapon;

#endif
```

augments.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Angel.h"
#include "Augments.h"
#include "LD33.h"

Augments::Head::Head(Augments::Head_Type x) : type(x) {
  switch ( x ) {
    case Head_Type::head:
      SetSprite("Images\\head.png");
    break;
  };
};

void Augments::Head::Update(float dt) {
  SetPosition(Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().X,
              Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().Y-
                MathUtil::ScreenToWorld(Vec2i(0,40)).Y);
};

Augments::Body::Body(Augments::Body_Type x) : type(x) {
  switch ( x ) {
    case Body_Type::body:
      SetSprite("Images\\body.png");
    break;
  };
}

void Augments::Body::Update(float dt) {
  SetPosition(Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().X,
              Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().Y);
}

Augments::Weapon::Weapon(Augments::Weapon_Type x ) : type(x) {
  switch ( x ) {
    case Weapon_Type::sword:
      SetSprite("Images\\weapon.png");
    break;
  }
}

void Augments::Weapon::Update(float dt) {
  SetPosition(Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().X,
              Game::thePlayer->GetPosition().Y-
                MathUtil::ScreenToWorld(Vec2i(0,-40)).Y);
}
```

monster.h

```
// monster related

#include "Augments.h"
#include "Angel.h"

#ifndef MONSTER_H_
#define MONSTER_H_

namespace Player {
  // contains information like health attack etc
  // but more important body types
  class Monster : public PhysicsActor {
    int max_health, curr_health;
    int attack_damage;
    Augments::Head* frame_head;
    Augments::Weapon* frame_weapon;
    Augments::Body* frame_body;
  public:
    void Refresh(float dt);

    int R_Max_Health() const;
    int R_Curr_Health() const;
    int R_Attack_Damage() const;

    Augments::Head* R_Frame_Head();
    Augments::Weapon* R_Frame_Weapon();
    Augments::Body* R_Frame_Body();


    void Set_Max_Health(int);
    void Set_Curr_Health(int);
    void Add_Curr_Health(int);
    void Set_Attack_Damage(int);
    // will automatically remove old
    // actors from the stage and deallocate
    void Set_Frame_Head(Augments::Head_Type);
    void Set_Frame_Weapon(Augments::Weapon_Type);
    void Set_Frame_Body(Augments::Body_Type);


    Monster(Augments::Head_Type,
            Augments::Weapon_Type,
            Augments::Body_Type);
  };

};

using PlMonster = Player::Monster;


#endif
```

monster.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Monster.h"
#include "Augments.h"
#include "Angel.h"

void Player::Monster::Refresh(float dt) {


};

int Player::Monster::R_Max_Health()    const { return max_health; }
int Player::Monster::R_Curr_Health()   const { return curr_health; }
int Player::Monster::R_Attack_Damage() const { return attack_damage; }

Augments::Head*   Player::Monster::R_Frame_Head()    { return frame_head; }
Augments::Body*   Player::Monster::R_Frame_Body()    { return frame_body; }
Augments::Weapon* Player::Monster::R_Frame_Weapon()  { return frame_weapon; }


void Player::Monster::Set_Max_Health(int x)  { max_health = x; }
void Player::Monster::Set_Curr_Health(int x) { curr_health = x; }
void Player::Monster::Add_Curr_Health(int x) { curr_health += x; }
void Player::Monster::Set_Attack_Damage(int x) { attack_damage = x; }

void Player::Monster::Set_Frame_Head(Augments::Head_Type x) {
  if ( frame_head != nullptr ) {
    frame_head->Destroy();
    delete frame_head;
    frame_head = nullptr;
  }
  frame_head = new Augments::Head(x);
  theWorld.Add(frame_head);
};
void Player::Monster::Set_Frame_Weapon(Augments::Weapon_Type x) {
  if ( frame_weapon != nullptr ) {
    theWorld.Remove(frame_weapon);
    delete frame_weapon;
    frame_weapon = nullptr;
  }
  frame_weapon = new Augments::Weapon(x);
  theWorld.Add(frame_weapon);
};
void Player::Monster::Set_Frame_Body(Augments::Body_Type x) {
  if ( frame_body != nullptr ) {
    theWorld.Remove(frame_body);
    delete frame_body;
    frame_body = nullptr;
  }
  frame_body = new Augments::Body(x);
  theWorld.Add(frame_body);
};


Player::Monster::Monster(Augments::Head_Type head,
                  Augments::Weapon_Type weapon,
                  Augments::Body_Type body) {
  frame_body = nullptr;
  frame_head = nullptr;
  frame_weapon = nullptr;
  Set_Frame_Body(body);
  Set_Frame_Head(head);
  Set_Frame_Weapon(weapon);
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LD33.h"
#include "Angel.h"


int main ( ) {
  Game::Initialize();
  theWorld.StartGame();
  theWorld.Destroy();
  return 0;
}
```

Errors include things such as:

```
Error   43  error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall Player::Monster::R_Attack_Damage(void)const " (?R_Attack_Damage@Monster@Player@@QBEHXZ) already defined in Augments.obj  C:\Users\The Shire\Desktop\ludum_dare\ludumdare33\Code\ClientGame\source.obj    ClientGame

Error   3   error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall Player::Monster::Set_Frame_Body(enum Augments::Body_Type)" (?Set_Frame_Body@Monster@Player@@QAEXW4Body_Type@Augments@@@Z) already defined in Augments.obj   C:\Users\The Shire\Desktop\ludum_dare\ludumdare33\Code\ClientGame\LD33.obj  ClientGame
```

And it pretty much states similar for every single function in Monster.

Sorry for just dumping a ton of code. I've been trying to debug it for awhile but couldn't come up with any reasonable solution. I have the include guards, I don't see any namespace conflicts, and everything that needs to be defined is outside of the header files. I can't find anything in augments.h that would be causing this. I also thought it might be the enums, but replacing them with just int did not work either.

I'm thinking it might be the order of the include files? hmm. Maybe there's somehow multiple source files somewhere but I would have no clue as to how. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't included a CPP file rather than a header somewhere? How are you compiling and linking? What's in LD33.h?

Comment: I'm betting LD33.h (which isn't displayed) #include's monster.cpp

Comment: Yep it was monster.cpp but I resolved this when Alan made his first post. Dumb mistake on my part. I was waiting for Alan to post an actual answer post so I can mark this as resolved but i'll do it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had included Monster.cpp in another header file on accident! Oops